# How to add the library live to my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I can create my jar file and add it to my android project as a library and use it. But I want any time I made a change in my library, without recopying jar file to my project, apply changes in it.

**I don't want use Git**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push the .jar as an artifact to JFrog or some Artifact Hosting Repository. It'll give you a unique URL which can then be included in your Gradle file.

Everytime you push your new Artifact, you'd mostly increment the version number, so you'll need to do the same in your project. Just like you would for any other library.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=46107909#content/view/46107909

Comment: can you give me a tutorial link to upload my jar file and get a unique URL that can then be included in my Gradle file? Is there any other site?

Comment: A lot. Look them up: Maven, Nexus, Jelastic, JFrog, Artifactory.